# Android: Recargar fragment desde el mismo fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, idioma

,buenas a todos.

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy usando fragments para mostrar las distintas vistas.
Tengo un fragment que es CONFIGURACION, desde el, puedo entre otras cosas, cambiar el idioma y lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = new Locale(idioma);
c.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

El problema que tengo es que tengo que irme a otro fragment y volver a CONFIGURACION ,para poder ver los cambios en esa vista, no estoy podiendo reiniciarla o no estoy entendiendo como...
Que puedo hacer? Gracias!

Comment: Solo necesitas cambiar el idioma?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Claramente si, solamente necesito cambiar el idioma, con ese codigo que pase, puedo hacerlo a partir de android 7, que es una desventaja, el problema es que al cambiarlo de esa forma, tengo que reiniciar el fragment para poder visualizar los cambios, y es algo que no estoy podiendo, si tenes una mejor solucion, encantado :D

Comment: Por que como dije antes, funciona a partir de android 7 y el minimo de mi aplicacion es 4.4.4

Comment: Pero el string.xml se hizo para poner todo el texto ahi y que se traduzca toda la aplicación solo traduciendo ese archivo.

Comment: Te responderé en un momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para traducir tu app debes agregar todo tu texto al archivo string.xml para agregar un texto en este se debe efectuar de esta manera:
`<string name=”TextView”>Nombre</string>`  aqui agregamos el texto *nombre* a nuestro archivo **string.xml**. Para hacer que se muestre este texto en un elemento, por ejemplo un *textview* tan solo en la propiedad text agregamos `@string/TextView` es decir la referencia al archivo **string.xml** y el *name* de nuestro string o texto.

Si queremos agregar el texto por medio de código lo hacemos de la misma manera como si fuera una variable string.

Luego de hacer los cambios en toda nuestra app tan solo debemos traducir el **String.xml** y para hacerlo debemos crear otro **String.xml** pero con el texto traducido. Esto lo hacemos de la siguiente manera:
Por ejemplo:

Hacer clic con el botón derecho en el menú App > Res > Values y elegir “New Values Resource“.

Automáticamente veremos cómo se nos habilitan dos columnas nuevas: Language y Region. Aquí debemos elegir el idioma y la región que correspondan con el idioma al que vamos a traducir, por ejemplo, “es: Spanish” y “Any Region” de manera que esa traducción será “al español” para todas las regiones de habla hispana.

Pulsamos sobre “Ok” y listo, se creará un nuevo strings con el icono de la bandera de España, indicando que dicho fichero almacena la traducción al español.

Tan solo debemos rellenar este archivo **String.xml** pero con el texto traducido al otro idioma.

Una vez cambiados los textos, nuestra aplicación ya estará traducida y será multi-idioma, cargando por defecto la traducción acorde al sistema de nuestro Android.

Es decir si tu Android esta en español cargara el **string.xml** adecuado para ese idioma, así para los demás.

Un ejemplo para cambiar el idioma:

```
Locale localizacion = new 
Locale("es", "ES");
Locale.setDefault(localizacion);
Configuration config = new 
Configuration();
config.locale = localizacion;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

El ejemplo es para cambiar a español, pero para algunos idiomas existen constantes como para el ingles:

```
Locale localizacion =new Locale (Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[Fuente y más información](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/desarrollo/curso-de-desarrollo-android-tema-15-strings-xml-como-usar-los-textos-y-traducciones/)
[Clase locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale?hl=es)

Comment: Bien, tengo entendido todo hasta el momento, y asi esta funcionando mi aplicacion, lo unico, que decidi agregarle un selector de idioma, ya que si mi idioma default seria **ESPAÑOL**, pero el usuario no tiene traduccion a su idioma, y prefiere **INGLES** que **ESPAÑOL**, pueda cambiarlo, por eso mismo tengo ese codigo de arriba, y no esta resultando funcionar en android < 7, si no se puede, me quedo tranquilo con que porlomenos reconocera su region y lo traducira a ** español ; ingles ; portugues**

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, mira si te sirve.

Comment: Sigo en la misma posicion, de que para ver los cambios del idioma en el fragment, debo actualizarlo cambiando a otro fragment y volviendo al mismo, lo que no estoy pudiendo es que al cambiar el idioma desde mi spinner, los cambios se vean reflejados en el momento, ya sea reiniciando el fragment o desde otro metodo

Comment: Solo se me ocurre algo

Comment: Para actualizar tu fragmento

Comment: Yo crearia un sharedpreference al cambiar el idioma y cierro ese fragment cargando otro que el metodo oncreate lea el valos de sharedpreference y cargue de nuevo el fragmento que necesitas. Es un poco lio pero creo que funcionaría.

Comment: Sabes que pude actualizarlo de la siguiente manera?

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_configuracion, new f_Configuracion(), "tag_configuracion").addToBackStack("tag_configuracion").commit();

Comment: Igual voy a marcar tu respuesta como correcta, por que me ayudo a comprender varias cosas mas sobre el idioma que no tenia en cuenta, gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: gracias a ti. Muy interesante lo de " getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_configuracion, new f_Configuracion(), "tag_configuracion").addToBackStack("tag_configuracion").commit();"